# How can a browser extension alter the image

Tags: image, browser, rendering

I have an April fools prank in mind and I will probably need some time to figure it out, so that's why I'm early:

I want to install an extension in the browser (needs to target botch FF and IE, so a cross browser implementation would be best) of my friend so that if he hits the news page he is visiting every morning, a fake image will make him think that he has been selected. The problem is, that I cannot just swap the images. I have to use the actual image from that website and put his head on the body of someone else.

I do have some graphics guys that can do that sort of stuff. My problem over here is to hook into the rendering process and do my own alterations to the image before it gets rendered. That is, taking the image, doing stuff to it and then passing in the modified image to the browser so that it is being redered instead of the original one.

Is that possible using extensions? If it may be only possible with eihter FF or IE, I might get him to use the browser of choice but I'd highly appreciate your suggestions, code snippets and starting points for research. Are there browser extensions that can do similar stuff?

Cheers everyone. There is a lot of reputation in that game so I don't care if it takes weeks or even months to complete the job.

Thank you guys, looking forward to suggestions!

Max

Comment: I don't believe that you have good intentions here, and I don't want to help you to deceive people.

Comment: Along this you don't have much reputations so that community can trust on you.Really you are too early.

Comment: That's noble of you, but you are mistaken. Sorry to not be helped

Answer (score 1):

I think your intentions are harmless, but I must warn you: not all people may find your prank funny. But if you are sure that your friend will enjoy such a prank, it's really easy to set up.

You can use [BFilter](http://bfilter.sourceforge.net/) with site-specific filter to replace the image URL (it is very easy, just look at its examples and documentation). So when the user tries to open the web-page he will see your image instead of original picture. BFilter can be used as transparent proxy. I do not know how to setup transparent proxy in Windows, so you have to figure this part yourself. Alternatively, you can configure all installed browsers to use your filtering proxy.

You can use any other filtering proxy instead of BFilter.